Is this the correct method for determining Power at a given alpha, VAF, and coverage threshold?
I'm trying to calculate power at a given VAF, target coverage, and alpha. For example, what would my power be for a 100x coverage site, detecting VAF of 0.10 with an alpha of 0.05. This is what I came up with, in R, but I would like confirmation that this is the correct way to proceed.
coverage <- 100
VAF <- 0.10
alpha <- 0.05
alternative_VAF <- 0.5 

mean <- coverage * VAF
std_dev <- sqrt(coverage * VAF * (1 - VAF))
critical_value <- qnorm(1 - alpha, mean, std_dev)

alt_mean <- coverage * alternative_VAF
alt_std_dev <- sqrt(coverage * alternative_VAF * (1 - alternative_VAF))
power <- 1 - pnorm(critical_value, alt_mean, alt_std_dev)

In theory this should allow me to calculate the power of an assay.

Please [edit] your question and start from the beginning. What are you doing? Are you analyzing genetic variants? What is "power" in this context? Why do you want to calculate it? What will it tell you? We can't know if it's the right way to proceed unless we know where it is you want to proceed towards.
